# Create Json from Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Being new to Spark, I am working on something and facing difficulty. Any leads will help.
I am trying to create a JSON from dataframe which I have but toJSON function is not helping me out. So my output data frame is something like below :-

```
+---------+------------------+-------------------------+
|booking_id|    status           |count(status)|
+---------+------------------+-------------------------+
|  132         |     rent count.       |                        6|
|  132         |     rent booked     |                      24|
|  132         |     rent delayed    |                        6|
|  134         |     rent booked     |                      34|
|  134         |     rent delayed.   |                       21|
```

The output I am looking for is a dataframe which will contain booking id and status and its count as Json

```
+---------+-------------------------------------------+
|booking_id|    status_json         
+---------+-------------------------------------------+
|  132         |   { "rent count": 6, "rent booked": 24, "rent delayed": 6}  
|  134        |     { "rent booked": 34, "rent delayed": 21}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First create a `map` column with staus and countstatus columns. Then `groupBy`, `agg(collect_list("yourmapcolumn"))`, finally call `toJSON`

Answer (score 3):

For **`Spark2.4`**, use **`map_from_arrays`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy("booking_id").agg(F.to_json(F.map_from_arrays(F.collect_list("status"),F.collect_list("count(status)")))\
                              .alias("status_json"))\
                              .show(truncate=False)


#+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
#|booking_id|status_json                                       |
#+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
#|132       |{"rent count":6,"rent booked":24,"rent delayed":6}|
#|134       |{"rent booked":34,"rent delayed":21}              |
#+----------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  val sourceDF = Seq(
    (132, "rent count", 6),
    (132, "rent booked", 24),
    (132, "rent delayed", 6),
    (134, "rent booked", 34),
    (134, "rent delayed", 21)
  ).toDF("booking_id", "status", "count(status)")

  val resDF = sourceDF
    .groupBy("booking_id")
    .agg(to_json(collect_list(map(col("status"), col("count(status)")))).alias("status_json"))

  //  +----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
  //  |booking_id|status_json                                             |
  //  +----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
  //  |132       |[{"rent count":6},{"rent booked":24},{"rent delayed":6}]|
  //  |134       |[{"rent booked":34},{"rent delayed":21}]                |
  //  +----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```